# Dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version alongside with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, asus

I have problem with regards to dual booting. I have successfully downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 version, and with the help of Rufus I prepared bootable flash drive, then I restarted my computer and went to BIOS menu. I chose bootable flash drive and went ahead.

So it was here where the problem started. After checking files the entire system got stuck, and it was written that "failed to create karnel channel -22" and "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" and after waiting for 2 hours I shut down computer manually.

I tried so many ways and searched a lot via YouTube, groupmates, etc. My BIOS mode is UEFI, not Legacy. My computer model is Asus Tuf-gaming-505gt. It has a high storage. I allocated 1 TB entire free space for it. Before that I had installed Ubuntu 19.04 version (if I remember exactly), and it was successful enough, but it could not be updated and upgraded; therefore I deleted it. Other specs of my computer:

- Intel core i7 9th generation.
- RAM 16 GB
- 512 GB and 1 TB SSD disks

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: If the file check failed it's probably because your installation media is invalid. You need to either verify the checksum of the downloaded ISO, or use the BitTorrent link which auto-verifies.  It's also possible that you made the wrong choices in Rufus (easy to do).  Try Etcher instead to flash the ISO since it's fairly immune to user error/mistake and it also will auto verify the flash.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Booting in UEFI mode. And with 20.04 you may need the safe graphics mode or add nomodeset for nVidia. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Have you tried to write and make the Boot-able USB Flash using 'dd' instead of 'iso' option?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try may be to turn off secure boot. I've encountered similar issues and that has resolved them